# Matrix analog of Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

If I know a function $f(t)$ at times $t_0$ and $t_2$ then I know there must be a $t_1$ between $t_0$ and $t_2$ such that:

$$\lim_{t \to t_1}\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{f(t_0) - f(t_2)}{t_0 - t_2} $$

Is there an analog of this when $f$ is a square matrix and function of $t$?

Comment: You mean the mean value Theorem, don't you?

Comment: @Shaqinho yes I forgot :P

Comment: Okay I'll write an answer.

Comment: Why does $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}$ have a limit as $t\to t_1$?  Also what you stated is not true, e.g., $f$ is the curve $t\mapsto(\cos t,\sin t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $t_0=0$, $t_2=2\pi$ and you cannot find such a $t_1$.

Comment: @user10354138 I could write $f'(t_1)$ instead see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem for the Mean Value theorem

Comment: No, that is completely different.  (a) there is no reason why the limit $\lim_{t\to t_1}f'(t)$ exists, and (b) you don't know $f'$ is continuous at your $t_1$.

Comment: @user10354138 i don't think MVT holds for discontinuous functions or when the limit does not exist

Comment: Huh?  The function $f$ is differentiable, but the derivative $f'$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

There should indeed be an analog: Let $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ that is $C^1$ in every matrix entry and $U$ has to be an interval. Let $g:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $g(\lambda) := f(\lambda t_1 + (1 - \lambda)t_2)$ for some arbitrary $t_1, t_2 \in U$. note that this is well defined as $U$ is an interval.

Then we have $g'(\lambda) = f'(\lambda t_1 + (1 - \lambda)t_2))(t_1-t_2)$ by the chain rule. By the fundamental theorem of calculus we conclude:
$$
f(t_1) - f(t_2) = g(1)-g(0) = \int^1_0 g'(\lambda)~\mathrm{d} \lambda = (t_1-t_2) \int^1_0 f'(\lambda t_1 + (1-\lambda)t_2)~\mathrm{d}\lambda
$$
I think this is all we can get. We do not get as strong a statement as in the case of one dimension because we have to Control $n^2$ matrix entries at the same time.